# How to get data in table format dynamically when form is submitted using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

When i'am submitting the form the data in the input fields should me display in the table
For me the data is coming to table but the rows are not adding, in table data is updating in row only.
When iam submitting the form multiple times the data is updating in row only.
How can rows add dynamically.
iam having two fields like room category and room animeties

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("roomCategoryController", ["$scope", function($scope){

$scope.submit = function(){
$scope.formdata = [];
var myObj = {};
myObj.category =  $scope.category;
myObj.amenities = $scope.amenities;
console.log("my data");
$scope.formdata.push(myObj);
$scope.category ='' ;
$scope.amenities = '';
 console.log($scope.formdata);
}
}])
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/multi-select/0.9.12/css/multi-select.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <main ng-app = "myApp">
    <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller = "roomCategoryController">
      <div class="container mt-4">
        <h3>Room Category</h3>
        <div class="col-12 d-flex">
          <div class="col-4">
            <p>Room Category</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-8">
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model = "category">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 d-flex">
            <div class="col-4">
              <p>Room Amenities</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8">
              <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" id="basic" ng-model = "amenities">
                      <option value="1">1</option>
                      <option value="2">2</option>
                      <option value="3">3</option>
                      <option value="4">4</option>
                      <option value="5">5</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </form>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='col-12'>
            <div class='col-md-4'>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="col-12">
          <table class="table mt-5 table-striped table-dark">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>S.No</th>
                <th>Room Category</th>
                <th>Room Amenities</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="x in formdata">
                <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                  <td>{{x.category}}</td>
                  <td>{{x.amenities}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="roomCategoryController.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/multi-select/0.9.12/js/jquery.multi-select.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have to  globally declare `$scope.formdata`.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("roomCategoryController", ["$scope", function($scope){
$scope.formdata = []; //add here
$scope.submit = function(){

var myObj = {};
myObj.category =  $scope.category;
myObj.amenities = $scope.amenities;
//console.log("my data");
$scope.formdata.push(myObj);
$scope.category ='' ;
$scope.amenities = '';
 //console.log($scope.formdata);
}
}])
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/multi-select/0.9.12/css/multi-select.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <main ng-app = "myApp">
    <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller = "roomCategoryController">
      <div class="container mt-4">
        <h3>Room Category</h3>
        <div class="col-12 d-flex">
          <div class="col-4">
            <p>Room Category</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-8">
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model = "category">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 d-flex">
            <div class="col-4">
              <p>Room Amenities</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-8">
              <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select class="form-control" id="basic" ng-model = "amenities">
                      <option value="1">1</option>
                      <option value="2">2</option>
                      <option value="3">3</option>
                      <option value="4">4</option>
                      <option value="5">5</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </form>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class='col-12'>
            <div class='col-md-4'>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submit()">Submit</button>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="col-12">
          <table class="table mt-5 table-striped table-dark">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>S.No</th>
                <th>Room Category</th>
                <th>Room Amenities</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr ng-repeat="x in formdata">
                <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
                  <td>{{x.category}}</td>
                  <td>{{x.amenities}}</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="roomCategoryController.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/multi-select/0.9.12/js/jquery.multi-select.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: global declaration is not an issue

Comment: Then ? where are you stuck ?

Comment: when ever we are submitting the data is added in table right. if you submit multiple times the data is not added in multiple rows, here the data is updating the previous data.

Comment: In my code data is binding new row, not updating previous data

Comment: check my answer